# jQuery - Memory leak/garbage collection with .remove()/.after()

Tags: jquery, memory, memory-leaks, garbage, jquery-after

After leaving my browser window open all weekend, I came in this morning to the office with a hosed IE.  I'm doing a 'stats' dashboard bar that updates every 30 seconds.

The return is an html string, as a full xcontents

I'm appending this to the DOM, after my 'real' div, #ajaxreturn, which actually hosues something else.  I want this to show up after it.

If it exists, remove it from the dom.
append result to dom.

```
$(function(){
function getAD() {
    var request = $.ajax({  
        url: "getdashboard/"
        ,  type: "GET"              
        ,  cache: false
        ,  dataType: "html"
    });
    request.done(function(msg) {
        if($('#adminbar').length){
            $('#adminbar').remove();
        }
        $('#ajaxreturn').after(msg);
    });
}

//INIT AND RELOAD INTERVALS

//get DashBoard
getAD();
//and then look for updates every 30 seconds
var gb = setInterval(getAD,3000);
});
```

My assumption was that this would destory or send it to garbage colelction.   But it doesn't seem to be the case.   I add about 15KB to my IE session every 30 seconds.

Should I be using something else besides remove()?

Answer (score 0):

As I know, jQuery caching everything and put it to $.cache

You need to disable caching, using:

`$.ajaxSetup({cache:false});`

`jQuery.cache = {}`

`Sizzle.selectors.cacheLength`
`$.expr.cacheLength = 1`
https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/wiki/Sizzle-Documentation#sizzleselectorscachelength--number